# Apply free shipping to total price

Tags: magento-1.8, shipping, shopping-cart, discount

I’ve got a problem. I’ve got at customer who has free shipping for orders on $200 and over.

The problem lies in the discounts she offers. 1 type of discount is the 10 for 9 price. So if the Subtotal reaches $201, then the customer gets free shipping, and if the customer has bought 10 for 9, then the customer will get the discount, and the Totalprice will end on maybe $175,-

So the customer will get at discount and free shipping, because of the cart rule is applied before the discount.

Is there any workaround / coding modifications I need to do, to correct this matter?

Thanks in advance - Thomas

Comment: What conditions for the Shopping Cart Price Rule you are using for the free shipping ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `Mage/Shipping/Model/Carrier/Freeshipping.php`
change

```
if (($request->getFreeShipping())
            || ($request->getBaseSubtotalInclTax() >=
```

to

```
    $quote2 = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
    $discountTotal = 0;
    foreach ($quote2->getAllItems() as $item){
        $discountTotal += $item->getDiscountAmount();
    }

    $this->_updateFreeMethodQuote($request);
    $sprice = $request->getBaseSubtotalInclTax() - $discountTotal;

    if (($request->getFreeShipping())
        || ($sprice >=
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the **free shipping carrier** to do this you could change this part:

```
if (($request->getFreeShipping())
            || ($request->getBaseSubtotalInclTax() >=
                $this->getConfigData('free_shipping_subtotal'))
```

You would need to alter to remove the `baseDiscountAmount` which is stored on the quote object.